# FullCalendar Events do not refresh after Ajax adds a new event

Tags: django, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar in Django app.

A Django form is used to collect data and add create an event, using an Ajax call to the view.

When I create a new event, I successfully add the event.

The problem is when I add the event I have to reload the page manually to see the new event in the calendar - which is defeating the purpose of using Ajax!

Below is the part of the script that handles the form success I use, can some please point me in the right direction?

```
    function handleFormSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $myForm[0].reset(); // reset form data
        $('#addEventModal').modal('hide')
        var event_arr = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', event_arr);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
    }
```